# Adding a window state (max,min etc.) listener in chrome app example

Tags: javascript, event-handling, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to have a function fire upon window state change (js already has an `onresize` function and firefox has a statechange listener, however going from min to max to restore is not a resize event).

manifest.json calls main.js:

main.js: [launches index.html]

```
window.chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
window.chrome.app.window.create('index.html',{id: "index"})});
```

index.html: [includes a div that should change upon window state change
through a call to htmlBoundScript.js]

```
<script src=htmlBoundScript.js></script>
<!--below should change when screen is maximized-->
<div id="window_state">state has not yet changed</div>
<!--it does not change-->
```

htmlBoundScript.js -> [Listens for state change and updates div in html]

```
chrome.app.window.onFullscreened.addListener(function()
    {
      var isMax = chrome.app.window.get('index').isMaximized();
      document.getElementById('window_state').innerHTML = 
      ("state has ... changed, isMax = " + isMax);
    });
//The above code does not behave as intended, 
//that is it does not change the div in the html
```

Following: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#event-onMaximized , however I'm sure there's a basic element that need adjustment.

Comment: You did not state: 1) What is the desired functionality? 2) What's wrong with the current code? You just have a code dump with a "guess the error" game attached. _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. "_

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/window-state

Comment: Thank you Sarah, your link was very helpful.

Comment: Xan: those guidelines are 'guidelines', however I updated the question to clarify for the SE reader what is going on. The intended behavior was included as comments in the index.html file. Updated the first line of the question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From SE's link:

```
chrome.app.window.current().onBoundsChanged.addListener(updateCurrentStateReadout);
function updateCurrentStateReadout() {
 if(chrome.app.window.current().isMaximized())
 {
   //do action ...
 }
}
```

However, still searching for an example of how to use the onFullscreened method.